# Make a bat file want for a program to be running then launch another one

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am currently trying to create a batch file that launches some programs for me.
This could easily be done with the command "start" but the last program it runs only works if the first one's window is active.

I have tried using a delay before the last program. But the first one does not use the same starting delay everytime, making me need sometimes a long delay or a short one.

So I thought I had to make the code wait for the process to be running and added a line of code to do so. But sometimes the first program has its process running without having the window active (in long delay situations mentioned above) so the delay ends and the last program fails to start.

Now i show how my batch file looks so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
start ..\pgr1.exe  {First Program}
start ..\prg2.exe  {Second Program}

:LOOP
C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq prg1.exe" |  {Get Tasklist}
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /i "prg1.exe" {Find First Program Process}
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO ROLL {Process Found}
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LOOP {Process not Found}

:ROLL
call Delayer5.exe {Wait 5 secconds}
start ..\prg1_pluginloader.exe {Program that needs prg1.exe to be active}
cls
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still use `tasklist.exe` like so:

```
tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq prg1.exe" /V | findstr "Your Window Title"
```

`/V` will print the window title of the window associated with the process, so you can use that check to control your loop.